# Runtime error "x + width must be <= bitmap.width()" on some devices

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bitmap

I'm creating a program that essentially creates a menu based on Rects and glyphs. For some reason this code works on the emulator AND my friends phone, but it doesn't work on mine. I'm starting to believe perhaps my phone is too old (being a comet series). However, like any good phone app dev, I want my app to work on any type of android phone, so I'm looking into this issue quite thoroughly. I get an error saying:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width()

The only place I use bitmap is in my glyphs class posted here:

```
package text;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;

public class Glyphs {

private Bitmap bitmap;

private Map<Character, Bitmap> glyphs = new HashMap<Character, Bitmap>(62);

private int width;
private int height;

private char[] charactersL = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
private char[] charactersU = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
private char[] numbers = new char[] { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0' };

public int getWidth(){
    return width;
}

public int getHeight(){
    return height;
}

public Glyphs(Bitmap bitmap){
    super();
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
    this.width = 12;
    this.height = 18;

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
        glyphs.put(charactersL[i], Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0 + (i * width), 0, width, height));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
        glyphs.put(charactersU[i], Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0 + (i * width), 24, width, height));
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        glyphs.put(numbers[i], Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0 + (i * width), 48, width, height));
    }
}

public Bitmap getBitmap(){
    return bitmap;
}

public void drawString(Canvas canvas, String text, int x, int y){
    if(canvas == null){
        //return a tag
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
        Character ch = text.charAt(i);
        if(glyphs.get(ch) != null){
            canvas.drawBitmap(glyphs.get(ch), x + (i * width), y, null);
        }
    }
}
}
```

However, this program works perfectly fine on other phones. I'm not exactly sure why it crashes on my old pos phone.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the Android versions of your phone and those of your friends.
2. You should find the line of your code that is causing the error.
3. Put here not only the error message itself, but the whole stack.
4. For future, install on Eclipse the Android source codes. So you'll find exactly, where the error happens. It helps much to understand.