# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width()

Tags: android, bitmap

I get this error from some devices. On my N5 everything is ok. But some devices, like a PRESTIGIO PMT3177 3G throws this exception.

setPic code:

```
// Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    if(photoW == 0) photoW = 1;
    if(photoH == 0) photoH = 1;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getCurrentPhotoPath(), bmOptions);

    if (bitmap != null) {

        Bitmap resizedbitmap = null;

        if (targetW > targetH){
            int start = (targetW - targetH) / 2;
            resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, start, 0, targetH, targetH);
        } else {
            int start = (targetH- targetW) / 2;
            resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, start, targetW, targetW); //here is exception
        }
```

Logcat:

```
 E/image_width﹕ 360
 E/image_height﹕ 360
 E/gridview_width﹕ 1080
 E/gridview_height﹕ 1557
```

i checked other same questions:
[Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502039/exception-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-x-width-must-be-bitmap-width)

[Runtime error "x + width must be <= bitmap.width()" on some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920293/runtime-error-x-width-must-be-bitmap-width-on-some-devices)

[IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width() in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852968/illegalargumentexception-x-width-must-be-bitmap-width-in-android)

[createBitmap --- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x must be < bitmap.width()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171509/createbitmap-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-x-must-be-bitmap-width)

But it continues to throw exception. Explain me pls, how to solve this problem?